# Return multidimensional char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

In C, how can I create a function which returns a string array? Or a multidimensional char array?

For example, I want to return an array `char paths[20][20]` created in a function.

My latest try is

```
char **GetEnv()
{
  int fd;
  char buf[1];
  char *paths[30];
  fd = open("filename" , O_RDONLY);

  int n=0;
  int c=0;
  int f=0;
  char tmp[64];

  while((ret = read(fd,buf,1))>0)
  {
    if(f==1)
    {
      while(buf[0]!=':')
      {
        tmp[c]=buf[0];
        c++;
      }
      strcpy(paths[n],tmp);
      n++;
      c=0;
    }
    if(buf[0] == '=')
      f=1;
  }
  close(fd);

  return **paths; //warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
  //return (char**)paths; warning: function returns address of local variable

}
```

I tried various 'settings' but each gives some kind of error.

*I don't know how C works*

Comment: Please show the code that creates array. Assuming that array is typed as `char**` you should `return array`, but you need to `malloc` it rather than declaring it on the stack. Remember that stack variables are only valid for the life of the stack frame in which they were declared.

Comment: You are returning a pointer to stack allocated memory. You can't do that' The compiler tells you not to. Allocate it on the heap.

Comment: I know the difference, I made the code work. But now I got another strange problem. After returning the array and successfully traversing and using it a function call (which was working earlier) is causing a trap.

Comment: It seems you didn't make it work if you have a trap. Let's be clear, you changed you declaration of paths to char** and used malloc like the answers told you declaration of paths to char** and used malloc like the answers told you

Comment: I have updated the answer, please see the code.

Comment: To solve the trap, instead of calling the concatenation function, I placed its code manually where it is needed. What could be causing that kind of trap?

Comment: this is a new question. Accept an answer here, and ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't safely return a stack-allocated array (using the array[20][20] syntax).

You should create a dynamic array using malloc:

```
char **array = malloc(20 * sizeof(char *));
int i;
for(i=0; i != 20; ++i) {
    array[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Then returning array works

Comment: What will be the syntax to return in that case? Same as I did?

Comment: You need to return something of type `char**`. In your code `paths` has that type.

Comment: Means i simple need to `return paths`?

Comment: @LifeH2O No you need to do it like how I outlined.  your `paths` is still stack allocated.

Comment: @life do you know the difference between the stack and the heap. Until you do you need to stop.@life do you know the difference between the stack and the heap. Until you do you need to stop.

Comment: I know the difference, I made the code work. But now I got another strange problem. After returning the array and successfully traversing and using it a function call (which was working earlier) is causing a trap.

Answer (score 3):

You should just return `array` (`return array;`). the `**` after declaration are used for dereferencing.

Also, make sure the the memory for this array is allocated on the heap (using `malloc` or simillar function)

Comment: @Foo Bah Original question said `return **array`.

Comment: his line was `return **array;` which does cause dereferencing.